# Function Definitions After Expressions in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I understand I can't define a function *inside* an expression, but I'm getting errors defining one *after* an expression within the same nested function. I'm using R5RS with DrScheme.

For example, this throws an error, *'define: not allowed in an expression context'*:

```
(define (cube x)
  (if (= x 0) 0) ;just for example, no reason to do this
  (define (square x) (* x x))
  (* x (square x)))
```

Comment: Actually, you *can* define a function inside an expression, simply not with the `define` syntax, which can be used only in certain contexts, but with `let`, for instance: `(+ 2 (let ((square (lambda(x) (* x x)))) (square 4)))`

Comment: The point of this question is that it's *not* inside of an expression. You get the same error with lambda syntax. There are a couple good answers that explain what's going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In R5RS you can only use `define` in rather specific places: in particular you can use it at the beginning (only) of forms which have a `<body>`.  This is described in 5.2.2.  That means in particular that internal `define`s can never occur after any other expression, even in a `<body>`.

Native Racket (or whatever the right name is for what you get with`#lang racket`) is much more flexible in this regard: what you are trying to do would (apart from the single-armed `if`) be legal in Racket.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use `define` inside another definition. Some Schemes won't allow you to have an `if` without the `else` part, though. This works for me:

```
(define (cube x)
  (if (= x 0) 0 1) ; just for example, no reason to do this
  (define (square x) (* x x))
  (* x (square x)))
```

Have you tried making the definition at the beginning? maybe that could be a problem with your interpreter.

Comment: Both R5RS and R7RS only specify that internal definitions can come between all expressions ([see the relevant section in R5RS here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-std/r5rs-Z-H-8.html#%_sec_5.2.2)). I don’t think it’s off-spec to permit them anywhere, but I think Racket’s implementation tries to fail fast and interpret the spec minimally when possible.

Comment: This is clearly outside the R5RS spec.  You have top level and in the beginning of the body of `lambda` and derived forms you may have local definitions. This is neither and clearly not comformant scheme code. Just like implementations that has more bindings than the spec it's ok if it happens to work in a particular implementation since it doesn't break Scheme code, but doing this makes implementation specific lock ins rather than standard conforming code.

Comment: Actually I did mention the interpreter I'm using specifically so @AlexisKing is correct.

Comment: Yes, @Sylwester, I think that’s more or less exactly what I said, albeit phrased a bit more clearly. :)

Answer (score 1):

`define` inside a procedure body (that includes all forms that are syntactic sugar for procedures, like `let`, `let*`, and `letrec`) are only legal before other expressions and never after the first expression and it can not be the last form.

Your example shows no real reason for why you would want to have an expression before definitions. There is no way you can get anything more than moving all `define` up to the beginning. eg.

```
(define (cube x)
  ;; define moved to top
  (define (square x) (* x x))
  ;; dead code moved under define and added missing alternative
  (if (= x 0) 0 'undefined) 
  (* x (square x)))
```

If the code isn't dead. eg. it's the tail expression you can use `let` to make a new body:

```
(define (cube x)
  (if (= x 0) 
      0
      (let ()
        ;; this is top level in the let
        (define (square x) (* x x))
        ;; required expression
        (* x (square x)))))
```

I think perhaps we would need an example where you think it would be warranted to have the define after the expression and we'll be happy to show how to scheme it up.

Comment: I was basically trying to handle some edge cases in numerical exercises from SICP knowing it wasn't the elegant way to go about it, but curious as to why it didn't work anyway. Apparently in some versions of Scheme it does, just not what I'm using.

Comment: @Sophia R5RS is a very short specification with lots of undefined areas. An implementation which disallows a lot of the undefined behaviors are Racket's `#!r5rs` so if you can get your code to work in it it would most likely work in the other implementations as well.